# How can I calculate the mean for specific values from a vector?

Tags: r, vector, sequence, mean

Let's say I have a vector

```r
x <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
```

I want to calculate the mean for the 1st, 21st, 41st, 61st and 81st values. And then for the 2nd, 22nd, 42nd, 62nd and 82nd values, and so on. Until I have a final vector of 20 values.

Is there a way of doing this with base R?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Jose, if any of the answers solved your problem consider to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Please also consider to accept answers given to your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11703997/jos%c3%a9-baltazar?tab=questions). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You may use `rowMeans` after you changed the dimensions to a 20x5 matrix

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
rowMeans(matrix(x, nrow = 20))
# [1]  0.48315816 -0.45278238  0.32392765  0.47993455 -0.19808804
# [6]  0.36215278  0.11231354  0.08840571  0.78022995  0.29911804
#[11]  0.48624850  0.32825670  0.49916741  0.03855425 -0.23844465
#[16] -0.21686072 -0.15059661 -0.88259531 -1.73071168  0.23890847
```

---

Another option is `tapply` and `rep_len`

```
out <- tapply(x, INDEX = rep_len(1:20, length(x)), mean)
```

Result

```
head(out)
#          1          2          3          4          5          6 
#  0.4831582 -0.4527824  0.3239276  0.4799346 -0.1980880  0.3621528
```

Comment: The `rowMeans` option is much better IMO.

Comment: @nicola I think so too. Will put this one on top.

Comment: `rowMeans` is 10x faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sapply` to go over `1:20` and add this to `0:4*20` like:

```
sapply(1:20, function(i) mean(x[i + 0:4*20]))
```